# Added a pre commit hook to central repo (or something similar)

Tags: git, gitlab, pre-commit-hook

Ok, so I have figured out how to add a pre-commit hook that checks for a message that will reference a JIRA item.

```
#!/bin/sh
test "" != "$(grep 'JIRA-' "$1")" || {
        echo >&2 "ERROR: Commit message is missing Jira issue number."
        exit 1
}
```

I add this to my local repo and all cool. Every commit I make to it has this commit message.
However, I am interested in the situation where there is a bunch of developers all committing to their local repos and then pushing / pulling to a remote master on GitHub. What I'd like is a similar mechanism for when the push changes to the remote repo on GitLab that they have to similarly reference a JIRA.

What is a good way to do this?

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned in [Sytse Sijbrandij](https://stackoverflow.com/users/613240/sytse-sijbrandij)'s[answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22556290/6309) by , and detailed in the "[GitLab Enterprise Edition](https://www.gitlab.com/gitlab-ee/)" page, GitLab EE now supports:

> **Git hooks rules** (commit message must mention an issue, prevent tag deletion, etc.)

But again, that is the *Enterprise* Edition (EE), not the community Edition (CE).
For the latter, see my original answer.

---

Original answer (August 2013)

You can add a `pre-receive` hook that would block any commit pushed to a gitlab-managed bare repo.

The difficulty, however, would be to add that hook for any new project (and repo) created through GitLab, as that [thread illustrates](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/gitlabhq/mgVGdS52c10).

Since [GitLab doesn't used gitolite anymore](http://blog.gitlab.org/gitlab-without-gitolite/), there is no easy or native way to do this (for now 5.X and 6.0).

> For now you could throw your hook in the hooks directory in `gitlab-shell` then modify https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlab-shell/blob/master/lib/gitlab_projects.rb#L46 to reflect.

#### `Gitlab-Shell/lib/gitlab_projects.rb`

```ruby
def create_hooks_cmd
  pr_hook_path = File.join(ROOT_PATH, 'hooks', 'post-receive')
  up_hook_path = File.join(ROOT_PATH, 'hooks', 'update')
  "ln -s #{pr_hook_path} #{full_path}/hooks/post-receive && ln -s #{up_hook_path} #{full_path}/hooks/update"
end
```

> to get our own centralized hooks in there.

Answer (score 1):

GitLab 6.7 Enterprise Edition will have 'Git hooks' that allow this.